# How to crop Screen Recordings under Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, screen-capture, quicktime

Quicktime Player for Snow Leopard now allows you record the screen.  Awesome!
Once you have a movie it will let you trim screen recordings for length.
Is there a way to crop the movie's dimensions, either in QT or using some built-in or free software?

**Update:** How to crop to an arbitrary size and aspect ratio? iMovie only seems to let you crop to the aspect ratio of the containing project.

**Result:** Both good answers but since I have QuickTime Player 7 and Photoshop, that's the workflow I choose as the answer. *NOTE: If you have Photoshop Extended, you can import a movie, use the crop tool, and Export the cropped movie. Not free or built-in, but convenient.*

**To summarize the instructions from the video link ricbax posted:**

1. Open movie in QuickTime Player 7
2. Copy a frame and Paste it into a new document in Photoshop
3. Draw a rectangular selection around the *area to keep* and fill with black
4. Invert the selection and fill with white
5. Save as .GIF, with 2 colors
6. Back in QuickTime Player 7, open Movie Properties window
7. Select the Video Track
8. Select the Visual Settings Tab
9. Drag and Drop the 2-color .GIF file onto the Mask drop area (or use choose file button)
10. Export the (now cropped) movie
    DONE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the video here:

[How to Use Quicktime to Crop Video with Letterbox/Pillarbox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeZDjX3o9mQ)

If you upgraded SL from Leopard you can do this via Quicktime 7 otherwise they have cut out all the awesome editing features from QT10. :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this directly while recording in QuickTime, but you can do it with QuickTime and iMovie.

I got the desired effect by

1. Doing a full screen recording
2. Opening the recording in iMovie
3. Using the "Cropping, Ken Burns and Rotation" tool under the Windows menu to crop just the region I wanted to show.
4. Export the iMovie to the desired format (under the iMovie Share menu)

Comment: Great answer! Most other solutions require paid software or tedious methods like using Photoshop to define a mask.

Answer (score 1):

iMovie allows for cropping the frame (at least in the iLife 09 version).

Apple has a tutorial video online at http://www.apple.com/ilife/tutorials/#imovie-crop