# quicktime recording: only a region?

Tags: macos, mac, quicktime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to crop Screen Recordings under Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/60089/how-to-crop-screen-recordings-under-snow-leopard)

The newest QT has a feature to record or capture the current screen. My iMac 27 is too big if I want to record the whole screen. Can I designate a region or an application window for recording? I could not find a way to do that. Not sure if I have to use alternative applications to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this directly while recording in QuickTime, but you can do it with QuickTime and iMovie.

I got the desired effect by

1. Doing a full screen recording
2. Opening the recording in iMovie
3. Using the "Cropping, Ken Burns and Rotation" tool under the Windows menu to crop just the region I wanted to show.
4. Export the iMovie to the desired format (under the iMovie Share menu)

Comment: doug, if you're going to vote-to-close a question, it's probably best not to post an answer to it.  instead, place your answer on the duplicate.  now that it's been closed-as-duplicate, go ahead and repost on the duplicate and delete this answer.

Comment: I answered before I thought to search for the duplicate.